# How to use streams in Deno?

Tags: javascript, deno, whatwg-streams-api

I am very confused on Deno documentation. It has `ReadableStream` and `WritableStream` API, but it doesn’t have a documentation to use it.

I want to read from `ReadableStream` and write to `WritableStream`, how can I do that in Deno?

Comment: is [this](https://deno.land/manual/examples/fetch_data#files-and-streamshttps://deno.land/manual/examples/fetch_data#files-and-streams) what you looking for ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to read from `ReadableStream` and write to `WritableStream`, how can I do that in Deno?

Here's a basic TypeScript example demonstrating manual use of the `readable` and `writable` parts of a [`TextEncoderStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoderStream) (which is a subtype of [`TransformStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TransformStream)) with verbose console logging:

`so-73087438.ts`:

```ts
const decoder = new TextDecoder();
const decode = (chunk: Uint8Array): string =>
  decoder.decode(chunk, { stream: true });

const stream = new TextEncoderStream();

(async () => {
  for await (const chunk of stream.readable) {
    const message = `Chunk read from stream: "${decode(chunk)}"`;
    console.log(message);
  }
  console.log("Stream closed");
})();

const texts = ["hello", "world"];

const writer = stream.writable.getWriter();
const write = async (chunk: string): Promise<void> => {
  await writer.ready;
  await writer.write(chunk);
};

for (const str of texts) {
  const message = `Writing chunk to stream: "${str}"`;
  console.log(message);
  await write(str);
}

console.log("Releasing lock on stream writer");
writer.releaseLock();
console.log("Closing stream");
await stream.writable.close();
```

```
% deno --version
deno 1.24.0 (release, x86_64-apple-darwin)
v8 10.4.132.20
typescript 4.7.4

% deno run so-73087438.ts
Writing chunk to stream: "hello"
Chunk read from stream: "hello"
Writing chunk to stream: "world"
Chunk read from stream: "world"
Releasing lock on stream writer
Closing stream
Stream closed
```

---

Covering the entirety of the API for [WHATWG Streams](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/) is out of scope for a Stack Overflow answer. The following links will answer any question you could ask about these streams:

- [Deno CLI APIs – ReadableStream | Deno Doc](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable/%7E/ReadableStream)
- [Deno CLI APIs – WritableStream | Deno Doc](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable/%7E/WritableStream)
- [Streams—The definitive guide](https://web.dev/streams/)
- [Streams API concepts - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Concepts)
- [Streams API - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API)
- [ReadableStream - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream)
- [WritableStream - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WritableStream)
- [Streams Standard](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/)

Comment: I just realized a couple minutes ago that Streams is a Web APIs adapted to Deno, and not a Deno APIs. Maybe this is why I dont found the doc on Deno